# Dos arrays en un mismo layout

Tags: android, json

Veréis, tengo este `.Json` el cual tiene varios arrays lo que quisiera es ver en dos listas, goles y minuto local en una y goles y minuto visitante en otra, pero me falla algo. Me pueden ayudar. Gracias

```
    public class Goles_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    // Atributos
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest;
    private static final String URL_BASE = "http://www.ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/server.php?action=getActa&tmp=2015/2016&jor=9&cmp=284&idl=0201045301&idv=0201239301";
    private static final String URL_JSON = "";
    private static final String TAG = "";
    private static final String ESCUDO = "http://ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/";
    List<Goles> items;
    List<Goles_V> items_v;

    public Goles_Adapter(Context context) {
        super(context,0);

        // Crear nueva cola de peticiones
        requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        // Nueva peticion JSONObject
        jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                URL_BASE + URL_JSON,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                      @override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        items = parseJson(response);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                      @override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error Respuesta en JSON: " + error.getMessage());

                    }
                }
        );

        // Anyadir peticion a la cola
        requestQueue.add(jsArrayRequest);
    }

      @override
    public int getCount() {
        return items != null ? items.size() : 0;
    }

      @override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        // Referencia del view procesado
        View listItemView;

        //Comprobando si el View no existe
        listItemView = null == convertView ? layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.goles_row,
                parent,
                false) : convertView;


        // Obtener el item actual
        Goles item = items.get(position);

        // Obtener Views
        TextView textoNombre = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_jornada);
        TextView textoMinuto = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Fecha);


        // Actualizar los Views
        textoNombre.setText(item.getNombre());
        textoMinuto.setText(item.getMinuto());

        View listItemView1;

        listItemView1 = null == convertView ? layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.goles_row,
                parent,
                false) : convertView;

        Goles_V item1 = items_v.get(position);

        // Obtener Views
        TextView textoNombre1 = (TextView) listItemView1.findViewById(R.id.tv_jornada1);
        TextView textoMinuto1 = (TextView) listItemView1.findViewById(R.id.tv_Fecha1);


        // Actualizar los Views
        textoNombre1.setText(item1.getNombre());
        textoMinuto1.setText(item1.getMinuto());

        // Anyadir peticion a la cola

        return listItemView;
    }

    public List<Goles> parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject){
        // Variables locales
        List<Goles> rankingAmonestacionesCadetes = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray jsonArray= null;

        try {
            // Obtener el array del objeto
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("golesLocal");

            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

                try {
                    JSONObject objeto= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Goles RankingAmonestacionesCadetes = new Goles(
                            objeto.getString("nombre"),
                            objeto.getString("minuto"));


                    rankingAmonestacionesCadetes.add(RankingAmonestacionesCadetes);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error de parsing: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        public List<Goles_V> parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject){
            // Variables locales
            List<Goles_V> goles_Visitante = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray jsonArray_visi= null;

            try {
                // Obtener el array del objeto
                jsonArray_visi = jsonObject.getJSONArray("golesVisitante");

                for(int i=0; i<jsonArray_visi.length(); i++){

                    try {
                        JSONObject objeto= jsonArray_visi.getJSONObject(i);

                        Goles_V goles_visitante = new Goles_V(
                                objeto.getString("nombre"),
                                objeto.getString("minuto"));


                        goles_Visitante.add(goles_visitante);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error de parsing: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return rankingAmonestacionesCadetes;
        }
    }
}
```

Pero en la linea

```
public List<Goles_V> parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject){
```

hay algo mal.

```
Error155, 9) error: illegal start of expression
Error155, 39) error: ';' expected
Error155, 61) error: ';' expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Bien e conseguido a medias este codigo me funciona correctamente cuando hay el mismo numero de items en cada array, osea empate, pero cuando hay mas items de locales que visitantes da este error:

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1

este es el codigo:

```
public class Goles_Adapter_J25 extends ArrayAdapter {

// Atributos
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest;
private static final String URL_BASE = "http://juveniles.esy.es/2015/jornadas/info_jornadas/info_j_25.php";
private static final String URL_JSON = "";
private static final String TAG = "";
private static final String ESCUDO = "http://ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/";
List<Goles_Local> items_local;
List<Goles_Visi> items_visi;

public Goles_Adapter_J25(Context context) {
    super(context,0);

    // Crear nueva cola de peticiones
    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    // Nueva peticion JSONObject
    jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URL_BASE + URL_JSON,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    items_local = parseJson_local(response);
                    items_visi = parseJson_visitante(response);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error Respuesta en JSON: " + error.getMessage());

                }
            }
    );

    // Anyadir peticion a la cola
    requestQueue.add(jsArrayRequest);
}

public int getCount() {
    return items_local != null ? items_local.size() : 0;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    // Referencia del view procesado
    View listItemView;

    //Comprobando si el View no existe
    listItemView = null == convertView ? layoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.goles_dos_listas_row,
            parent,
            false) : convertView;


    // Obtener el item actual
    Goles_Local item = items_local.get(position);

    // Obtener Views
    TextView textoNombre = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Nombre_Local);
    TextView textoMinuto = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Minuto_Local);


    // Actualizar los Views
    textoNombre.setText(item.getNombre());
    textoMinuto.setText(item.getMinuto());

    // Obtener el item actual
    Goles_Visi item_visi = items_visi.get(position);

    // Obtener Views
    TextView textoNombre1 = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Nombre_Visi);
    TextView textoMinuto1 = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Minuto_Visi);


    // Actualizar los Views
    textoNombre1.setText(item_visi.getNombre_visi());
    textoMinuto1.setText(item_visi.getMinuto_visi());





    // Anyadir peticion a la cola

    return listItemView;
}



public List<Goles_Local> parseJson_local(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    // Variables locales
    List<Goles_Local> goles_Local_local = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray jsonArray_Local = null;

    try {
        // Obtener el array del objeto
        jsonArray_Local = jsonObject.getJSONArray("golesLocal");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_Local.length(); i++) {

            try {
                JSONObject objeto = jsonArray_Local.getJSONObject(i);

                Goles_Local goles_Local_Local = new Goles_Local(
                        objeto.getString("nombre"),
                        objeto.getString("minuto"));


                goles_Local_local.add(goles_Local_Local);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error de parsing: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return goles_Local_local;
}

public List<Goles_Visi> parseJson_visitante (JSONObject jsonObject){
            // Variables locales
            List<Goles_Visi> goles_Visitante = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray jsonArray_visi = null;

            try {
                // Obtener el array del objeto
                jsonArray_visi = jsonObject.getJSONArray("golesVisitante");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_visi.length(); i++) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject objeto = jsonArray_visi.getJSONObject(i);

                        Goles_Visi goles_visitante = new Goles_Visi(
                                objeto.getString("minuto"),
                                objeto.getString("nombre"));


                        goles_Visitante.add(goles_visitante);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error de parsing: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return goles_Visitante;
        }
```

}

Comment: Rafael, que es lo que falla o no se muestra, tambièn podrìas agregar imagenes para tener idea de lo que se pregunta, Saludos. :)

Comment: Error155, 9) error: illegal start of expression
Error155, 39) error: ';' expected
Error155, 61) error: ';' expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: error: ';' expected indica que en alguna linea falta al final ';' , verifica tambièn en tus objetos Goles y Goles_V

Comment: Si, lo que no se es en cual.

Comment: Es un `json` interesante, ¿de qué manera haz definido tu `POJO` para realizar la conversión `json/java`?

Comment: Rosendo Ropher, mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que usted tinen los cierres mal pues tiene un metodo `public List<Goles>` sin cerrar donde añade otro `public List<Goles_V>` sin cerrar el anterior espero entienda.

```
      public List<Goles> parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            ..//

            try {
            ..//
    
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } <---- agregar este

        public List<Goles_V> parseJson (JSONObject jsonObject){
            ..//

            try {
            ..//

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
            return rankingAmonestacionesCadetes;
        }
    
    }

} <---- borrar uno del final
```

---

Ademas el metodo `public List<Goles> parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject)` usted tiene como retorno `List<Goles>` y este no esta presente en el codigo me imagino que usted quiera retornar `List<Goles> rankingAmonestacionesCadetes = new ArrayList<>();`.

Con lo que le quedaria algo asi por ejemplo:

```
        public List<Goles> parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            ..//
    
            List<Goles> rankingAmonestacionesCadetes = new ArrayList<>();
    
            try {
            ..//
    
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
         return rankingAmonestacionesCadetes; <--- agregar return
    
        } <---- agregar este
    
        public List<Goles_V> parseJson (JSONObject jsonObject){
            ..//
    
            try {
            ..//
    
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
            return rankingAmonestacionesCadetes;
        }
    }
} <---- borrar uno del final
```

---

### Update:

Me da la sensacion de que usted se confundio al mira el ejemplo que puse y mezclo los try o algo asi espero ahora le ayude mejor.

```
   public List<Goles> parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject){
        // Variables locales
        List<Goles> rankingAmonestacionesCadetes = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray jsonArray= null;

        try {
            // Obtener el array del objeto
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("golesLocal");

            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

                try {
                    JSONObject objeto= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Goles RankingAmonestacionesCadetes = new Goles(
                            objeto.getString("nombre"),
                            objeto.getString("minuto"));


                    rankingAmonestacionesCadetes.add(RankingAmonestacionesCadetes);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error de parsing: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         return rankingAmonestacionesCadetes;
    }

    public List<Goles_V> parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject){
            // Variables locales
            List<Goles_V> goles_Visitante = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray jsonArray_visi= null;

            try {
                // Obtener el array del objeto
                jsonArray_visi = jsonObject.getJSONArray("golesVisitante");

                for(int i=0; i<jsonArray_visi.length(); i++){

                    try {
                        JSONObject objeto= jsonArray_visi.getJSONObject(i);

                        Goles_V goles_visitante = new Goles_V(
                                objeto.getString("nombre"),
                                objeto.getString("minuto"));


                        goles_Visitante.add(goles_visitante);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error de parsing: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return rankingAmonestacionesCadetes;
     }
 }
```

---

Esto se lo dejo como detalle no supone ningun error pero si es fuera de la convencion.

```
Goles RankingAmonestacionesCadetes = new Goles(
                        objeto.getString("nombre"),
                        objeto.getString("minuto"));


                 rankingAmonestacionesCadetes.add(RankingAmonestacionesCadetes);
```

No supone ningun error el uso de `RankingAmonestacionesCadetes` que es el identificador/nombre que usted le asigna al objeto, pues usted esta usando PascalCase o UpperCamelCase, para el nombre y esto se suele usar para el nombre de las clases aunque no es obligatorio si es muy aconsejable seguir las convenciones o por lo menos las mas comunes puede mirar algo en este link:

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenci%C3%B3n_de_Nombres_(Programaci%C3%B3n)#Java

Se lo comento por si acaso porque veo que en casi la totalidad de su codigo usted usa Lower Camel Case (CamelCase) o alguna variacion para nombrar sus variable como por ejemplo aqui:

```
 List<Goles> rankingAmonestacionesCadetes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Y alomejor su IDE le autocompleto con `RankingAmonestacionesCadetes` porque tienen una clase con ese nombre o similar con ese nombre o lo a escrito en algun otro lugar.

Puede tratar algo asi:

```
Goles rankingAmonestacionesCadetes = new Goles(
                        objeto.getString("nombre"),
                        objeto.getString("minuto"));
```

O Cambiar el nombre `Goles rankingAmonestacionesCadetesTemp` para no mezclarlo con el de `rankingAmonestacionesCadetes = new ArrayList<>();`

```
Goles rankingAmonestacionesCadetesTemp = new Goles(
                        objeto.getString("nombre"),
                        objeto.getString("minuto"));

               rankingAmonestacionesCadetes.add(
                            rankingAmonestacionesCadetesTemp);
```

---

- `RankingAmonestacionesCadetes` -> PascalCase/UpperCamelCase
- `rankingAmonestacionesCadetes` -> LowerCamelCase/(CamelCase)

Comment: lo curioso en es que con las ediciones el } estaba dentro del formato, luego fuera y asi unas cuantas veces el formato de SO te estaba orientando (son bromas) . Saludos

Comment: Error:(157, 13) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(157, 43) error: ';' expected
Error:(157, 66) error: ';' expected
Error:(162, 17) error: 'try' without 'catch', 'finally' or resource declarations
Error:(184, 18) error: reached end of file while parsing
Error:(133, 9) error: 'try' without 'catch', 'finally' or resource declarations
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Rafa te recomiendo agregar también tus clases de los objetos.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa las siguientes líneas:

```
//Comprobando si el View no existe
listItemView = null == convertView ? layoutInflater.inflate(
        R.layout.goles_row,
        parent,
        false) : convertView;
```

El error está en que en un if abreviado no puedes usar ninguna sentencia que necesite de terminación.
Fíjate que el inflater termina en parentesis y a esto siempre le hace falta el punto y coma.
Prueba a cambiarlo a esto:

```
//Comprobando si el View no existe
if(listItemView == null){
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.goles_row,parent,false);
}else{
    convertView;
}
```

He visto que tienes repetidas estas sentencias al menos en dos casos.

Espero tu respuesta!

Comment: Gracias por la informacion, Si es verdad lo de los 2 puntos pero como me dices me da este error: Error:(87, 13) error: not a statement
Error:(157, 9) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(157, 39) error: ';' expected
Error:(157, 62) error: ';' expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Corrige los errores esos y pasame el nuevo error

Comment: Repetidas, creo que no; View listItemView;  -  View listItemView1; Para mostralo en dos listas. Este es el error que me da con lo qeu me dices que cambie:   Error:(87, 13) error: not a statement
Error:(110, 13) error: not a statement
Error:(159, 9) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(159, 39) error: ';' expected
Error:(159, 62) error: ';' expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:6 errors
Information:Total time: 4.738 secs
Information:BUILD FAILED

Comment: **Depura** el método de clase:
`public Goles_Adapter(Context context) {`
Ahí está ocurriendo el primer error.
Pero antes de nada corrige los puntos y comas que te dije en la contestación.

Comment: En este caso demasiado complicado para mi. Gracias

Comment: No te desesperes Rafa si puedes agrega tus clases para ayudarte a revisar donde estan los errores!

Comment: A que clases te refieres?. esa es la que tiene el error, con una lista me funciona perfectamente, pero me gustaría hacerlo en 2 listas para diferenciar locales y visitantes

Comment: Post 1 actualizado